# Is there a way with pygame to get keyboard input when the window is minimized?

Tags: python, pygame

Title says it all. Is there a way with pygame to get keyboard input when the window is minimized?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although you have to have it focused.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

pygame.display.iconify()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(event.key)
```

Otherwise it seems to not be possible according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815995/read-console-input-using-pygame) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567480/use-keyboard-without-calling-pygame-display-set-mode)

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. You don't happen to know any other framework which would allow you to get keyboard input when the window is minimized?

Comment: No, unfortunately not